# Weak linking static library in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to achieve weak linking with static libraries. I’ve read those two articles, "[Static Library on iOS](https://medium.com/swift-india/static-library-in-ios-d133123678d1)" and "[How Jesse Pinkman cracked Dynamic Library on iOS](https://medium.com/swift2go/how-jesse-pinkman-cracked-dynamic-library-in-ios-part-1-c6be383796b1)", which are really helpful.

However, I’m in a situation that I cannot achieve what I want. I’ve developed two frameworks, let’s call them `Main` and `Feature`, they can be installed both as pods and swift packages.

`Main` doesn’t have a dependency on `Feature`, nor `Feature` on `Main`, but if both `Main` and `Feature` are present on the podfile of the developer, then `Main` can use `Feature`’s functionality. This is achieved by adding the `Framework`’s path on the `Main`’s framework search paths in its podspec.

```
Main.podspec

# This works when use_frameworks! is added in the podfile.
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => [
      "$(inherited)",
      "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Feature",
    ],
}
```

This way, `Main` can use `Feature`’s functionality the following way

```
#if canImport(Feature)
print("SUCCESS!!!")
let feat = Feature()
feat.test()
#else
print(“Failed to import Feature“)
#endif
```

The problem starts when the integrating developer doesn’t include `use_frameworks!` In his podfile (e.g. React Native). `Main` and `Feature` are then built as static libraries, it compiles but it never gets inside the SUCCESS block.

After reading the above articles, I believe that the correct approach would be something like the following

```
Main.podspec

s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS" => [
      "$(inherited)",
      "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Feature",
    ],
    "SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS" => [
        "$(inherited)",
        "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Feature",
    ],
  }
```

And maybe also add

```
  Main.podspec

  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
   …
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => [
        "$(inherited)",
        '-ObjC',
        '-weak_library -l"Feature"'
    ],
    …
  }
```

I've tried the above with both `Defines module = YES/NO` on the `Feature`'s side.

```
Feature.podspec

s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES'
}
```

However, none of the above worked. Does anyone have any idea of what I might be doing wrong, or point me in some direction?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up mocking what you need [here](https://github.com/shahrukhalam/WeakLinkingPod).

But, I could solve only half (without `use_frameworks`) of your problem by:

```
Main.podspec

# To include Swift Module
'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => ['$(inherited)', '-Xcc -fmodule-map-file="${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Feature/Feature.modulemap"']
```

**Podspec Side:**

- Not sure why `modulemap` file path is needed with cocoapod setup (may be when a library is weakly linked)

**Podfile Side:**

- It will work without `use_frameworks`
- It won't work with `use_frameworks` as `modulemap` file won't be found in the specified path (as it considers only for static path scenario) & Xcode will think it's needed. Not sure how to optionally specify a `modulemap` file in the Podspec.

I hope I was able to help even though it's half way.

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you! I have to find a way to make it work with and without `use_frameworks`, but this is a big step forward. How did you conclude on `-Xcc -fmodule-map-file`? I'm going to iterate on it tomorrow, I'll let you know if I manage to do it.

Comment: To conclude on `-Xcc -fmodule-map-file`, I checked out https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-maps & `xcconfig`s that CocoaPods generates.

To make it work with and without `use_frameworks`, few options could be:
1. Specifying `use_frameworks` per pod which CocoaPods doesn't support as of now AFAIR.
2. Client making use of `pre_install` or `post_install` hooks.

Answer (score 0):

@e_pie I think what you are trying to do is a ***post_install*** stuff if you are clear about **Main**'s dependency on **Feature**.

So, the things you tried are actually perfect, but should be put on ***post_install*** like this in App's *Podfile*:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "Main"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] = "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Feature"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope it helps, please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: firstly thank you for the answer! I don't have access to the app's file, this could be any developer who decides to integrate my pod. So I'm trying to find another solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, the app & the pods build fine. Is there a possibility that the `#if canImport` doesn't work with static libraries? And that I should do it somehow else? E.g. with a compiler flag on the `Feature`'s side, that since I will have `$(inherited)` `Main`'s side, I can check if it exists or not.

Comment: `#if canImport` is supposed to work with modules, therefore I would expect it to work with the `Feature` when I have included `'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES'` in its podspec

Comment: @e_pie I am little confused about what you are trying to achieve.
-----
1. `#if canImport` would work if `Feature` is linked to `Main`

2. I think compiler flags are per Target basis. So, it wouldn't be available to `Main` from `Feature` if they are independent.

3. I think `DEFINES_MODULE` is default.
-----
I would suggest checking the same `#if canImport` code on App Target where `Feature` is already linked. What do you think.

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure if what I want to achieve is feasible only with Swift. The goal is to have an SDK, `Main`, which can use functionality from SDK `Feature`, if `Feature` has been added in the podfile. I don't have access in the `App` and its podfile, this is on someone's else side. I know that this can be done in ObjC using interoperability, because there I could check if `Feature` exists on the runtime. I don't mind whether this happens on build-time or run-time, but since both SDKs are written in Swift, I'm trying to avoid interoperability.

Comment: I checked what you suggested and `#if canImport(Feature)` works on the `App` target (both with and without `use_frameworks!`). As I have mentioned in the question, it also works in `Main` when podfile has `use_frameworks!`. It doesn't work though (in `Main`) when `use_frameworks!` is removed, i.e. in the case of React Native.